# Groups with a maximal subgroup which is solvable

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to know results on the structure of a finite group $G$ which possesses a maximal subgroup $H$, with $H$ solvable. More precisely, about
supplements of $H$, that is, decompositions $G=HK$ where the intersection of $H$ and $K$ is not necessarily the trivial subgroup. I know the question is a bit vague, but I would appreciate references to results of the form "there exists a supplement $K$ which satisfies ... "

Comment: This seems a very difficult question. For example, non-solvable groups with ALL maximal subgroups solvable were extremely difficult to classify ( done by J.G. Thompson in the 1960s).

Comment: I see. Well, partial results, even if they are small, are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following references answer the question in case of almost simple groups:

1. [The maximal factorizations of the finite simple groups and their automorphism groups](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-86-432/) by M. W. Liebeck, C. E. Praeger, and J. Saxl.

The book describes all possible factorizations by maximal subgroups of non-abelian finite simple groups.

2. [Factorizations of almost simple groups with a solvable factor, and
   Cayley graphs of solvable groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.0350.pdf) by Cai Heng Li and Binzhou Xia.

This unpublished paper classifies all almost simple groups factorizing on a solvable subgroup.

3. [On finite factorizable groups](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(84)90046-2) by Zvi Arad and Elsa Fisman.

The paper classifies all non-abelian finite simple groups $G=AB$ such that $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$. Assume $|B|$ is odd. Then $G$ is isomorphic to one of the following groups:

- $A_n$ ($n\geq5$ is a prime) and $A\cong A_{n-1}$;
- $M_{11}$ and either $A$ is solvable or $A\cong M_{10}$;
- $M_{23}$ and either $B$ is Frobenius of order $11\cdot23$ or $B$ is cyclic of order $23$ and $A\cong M_{22}$;
- $PSL(2,q)$ where either $q\in\{11,29,59\}$ and $A\cong A_5$ or $3<q\not\equiv1\pmod4$ and $A$ is solvable;
- $PSL(r,q)$ with $r$ an odd prime such that $\gcd(r,q-1)=1$ and either $G\cong PSL(5,2)$ and $|B|=5\cdot31$ or $A$ is a maximal parabolic subgroup such that $PSL(r-1,q)$ is involved in $A$. In particular, $B$ is either cyclic or Frobenius.